# Авторизация на ЧестныйЗнак.РФ с помощью C#

Tags: c#, api, token

Решил поделиться методом C# для авторизации на [ЧестныйЗнак.РФ](https://xn--80ajghhoc2aj1c8b.xn--p1ai/) так как сам маялся с поиском нужной информации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Check_SSCC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const String signerName = "*****@*****.***", //Константа для поиска сертификата, легче всего взять e-mail 
                     client_secret = "********-****-****-****-************", //Взят из ЧЗ
                     client_id = "********-****-****-****-************", //Взят из ЧЗ
                     user_id = "****************************************", //Можно взять как на ЧЗ, так и самому посмотреть (отпечаток сертификата)
                     auth_type = "SIGNED_CODE"; //Взят из ЧЗ
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyToken = token();
        . . . // Дальше делаем что хотели
    }

    private string token()
    {
        //code
        dynamic stuff, stuff2;
        string code_json, token_json;

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.mdlp.crpt.ru/api/v1/auth");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"client_secret\":\""+ client_secret + "\","+
                           "\"client_id\":\""+ client_id + "\","+
                           "\"user_id\":\""+ user_id + "\","+
                           "\"auth_type\":\""+ auth_type + "\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            code_json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            stuff = JObject.Parse(code_json);
        }

        //signature
        //  Переводим исходное сообщение в массив байтов.
        byte[] msgBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(stuff.code));
        //Поиск сертификата
        X509Certificate2 signerCert = GetSignerCert();
        //создаем подпись
        byte[] encodedSignature = SignMsg(msgBytes, signerCert);

        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedSignature);

        //token
        var httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.mdlp.crpt.ru/api/v1/token");
        httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter2 = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json2 = "{\"code\":\"" + Convert.ToString(stuff.code) + "\",\"signature\":\"" + signature + "\"}";

            streamWriter2.Write(json2);
        }

        var httpResponse2 = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader2 = new StreamReader(httpResponse2.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            token_json = streamReader2.ReadToEnd();
            stuff2 = JObject.Parse(token_json);
        }

        string token = Convert.ToString(stuff2.token);

        return token;
    }

    //  Открываем хранилище 'My' и ищем сертификат
    //  для подписи сообщения. Сертификат должен 
    //  иметь поля Субъект (subject name) "*****@****.***".
    static public X509Certificate2 GetSignerCert()
    {
        //  Открываем хранилище My.
        X509Store storeMy = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        storeMy.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        //  Ищем сертификат для подписи.
        X509Certificate2Collection certColl = storeMy.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, signerName, false);

        //  Проверяем, что нашли требуемый сертификат
        if (certColl.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Сертификат не найден");
        }

        storeMy.Close();
        //  Если найдено более одного сертификата,
        //  возвращаем первый попавшийся.
        return certColl[0];
    }

    //  Подписываем сообщение секретным ключом.
    static public byte[] SignMsg(Byte[] msg, X509Certificate2 signerCert)
    {
        //  Создаем объект ContentInfo по сообщению.
        //  Это необходимо для создания объекта SignedCms.
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(msg);

        //  Создаем объект SignedCms по только что созданному
        //  объекту ContentInfo.
        //  SubjectIdentifierType установлен по умолчанию в 
        //  IssuerAndSerialNumber.
        //  Свойство Detached устанавливаем явно в true, таким 
        //  образом сообщение будет отделено от подписи.
        SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);

        //  Определяем подписывающего, объектом CmsSigner.
        CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(signerCert);

        //  Подписываем CMS/PKCS #7 сообщение.
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);

        //  Кодируем CMS/PKCS #7 подпись сообщения.
        return signedCms.Encode();
       }
    }
}
```

**Всё что Вам нужно, так:**

1. изменить ***константы***;
2. вставить ***`string MyToken = token()`*** в своё событие;
3. скопировать к себе функции ***`private string token()`***, ***`static public X509Certificate2 GetSignerCert()`*** и ***`static public byte[] SignMsg(Byte[] msg, X509Certificate2 signerCert)`***;
4. Установить ***пакет Newtonsoft.Json*** (так парсить JSON легче, использовал его).

Comment: Для .NET Core 3.1/.NET 5 и выше есть встроенный парсер JSON - `System.Text.Json`. Пакет `Newtonsoft.Json` актуален только для древних фреймворков 4.x

Comment: Конечно хорошо, что вы самостоятельно нашли решение, но ведь можно это все написать более... правльно...? `WebRequest` является устаревшим, его сами Microsoft не советуют использовать. Говорите про `Newtonsoft.Json`, а сами пишите `string json = "{\"client_secret\":...`. Да и вообще, C# это объектно-ориентированный язык, тут все устроено на классах, методах и прочем, то есть эта, к примеру вся портянка (`const String signerName...`) должна быть как отдельный класс, сама работа с API, тоже, отдельный класс. И да, этот код еще и повесит интерфейс, ибо нет асинхронности.

Comment: @aepot, в текущем решении версия 4.6.1

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, никто не идеален, знаю только основы данного языка. Выложите свой вариант

Comment: @MaxDown Так я и не говорю про идеальность, я говорю про базу, основу основ языка. Я указал вам на ошибки и недочеты, чтобы вы поняли, что не так и что можно изменить. Вы ведь учитесь (это видно), так пытайтесь сделать правильно. Хорошо, ну вот вы новичок, знаете основы, ок. Вы увидели небось в интернете отправку запроса через `WebRequest`, что мешает зайти в документацию и проверить что за класс, как работает и так далее? А там бы и увидели "Не рекомендуется для использования в проектах". Не оправдывайте код тем, что вы новичок, лучше поймите недочеты и постарайтесь их исправить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, хорошо, я Вас услышал

Comment: Вот, смотрите как просто `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { client_secret = client_secret, client_id = client_id, user_id = user_id, auth_type = auth_type});`

Comment: По поводу очень давно устаревшего WebRequest - используйте [HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8). А вот эта статья поможет понять, что к чему - [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: `в текущем решении версия 4.6.1` - надеюсь у вас есть непреодолимая причина использовать эту древность. Например поддержка Windows XP. Других причин я не вижу. Если же причин нет - переезжайте на .NET 5 как можно скорее.

Comment: @aepot, `непреодолимая причина использовать эту древность` - работоспособность должна быть от XP до 10

Comment: @aepot, возможно ли, что из-за `WebRequest` я не могу обработать ответ от сервера?

Comment: `из-за WebRequest я не могу обработать ответ` Без понятия. Для меня не понятно, что такое "не могу". `от XP до 10` я немного ошибся, для XP [нужен фреймворк 4.0](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_programs/what-is-the-latest-version-of-net-40-for-windows/79fd95f1-9de0-455f-b044-8e1f8ad18e85). Так что 4.6.1 уже не влезает даже в висту. Но Vista вроде поддерживается в 4.6. Стоит ли ради ничего сидеть на 4.6.1? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies А .NET 5 прекрасно работает под семеркой.

Comment: @aepot, ну я тоже ошибся, от 7 до 10 системы стоят. Я посмотрел, попытался в .NET 5 - трудно понимать после Framework. Большого функционала не требуется, думаю оставлю так. Но посмотрю в сторону `HttpClient`

Comment: @MaxDown как минимум поднимите версию фреймворка до 4.7.2, для вас ничего не поменяется, а начинка у 4.7.2 значительно бодрее и стабильнее, чем у 4.6.1.